# Convert a List of employees into Multiple Maps grouping them by each of the employee attributes

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of employees :

Here is an example :

```
Employee e1 = {"empId": "1", "name": "Jack","languages": ["Java","React","R","Flutter"]}
Employee e2 = {"empId": "2", "name": "Jill","languages": ["Java","C"]}
Employee e3 = {"empId": "3", "name": "Mark","languages": ["Cobol"]}
Employee e4 = {"empId": "4", "name": "Michael","languages": ["React","R","Flutter"]}
Employee e5 = {"empId": "5", "name": "Jill","languages": ["Node","Cobol"]}
```

These employees are in a List : `List<Employee> employeeList`

The Employee object is a simple POJO:

```
public class Employee {
    private String empId;
    private String name;
    private List<String> languages;
```

I need to convert this Employee List into multiple Maps :

( for each attribute of employee )

```
Map m1 >> key = id , value = List<String> containing id which are same 

Map m2 >> key = name , value = List<String> containing ids for employee's with the same name

Map m3 >> key = each value in languages list , value = List<String> containing ids for employee's 
who have the same language
```

So here is the output I need :

```
Map mapById = [{"1",List<String>("1")},
               {"2",List<String>("2")},
               {"3",List<String>("3")},
               {"4",List<String>("4")}
               {"5",List<String>("5")}];
```

Agree the grouping by employee id does not make sense as there can never be two employees with the same id , so we can ignore the part based on employee Id , but I need to group on many more attributes of employee ( last name , city , etc )

```
Map mapByName = [{"Jack",List<String>("1")},
                 {"Jill",List<String>("2","5")},
                 {"Mark",List<String>("3")},
                 {"Michael",List<String>("4")}]
```

Note that in above Jill occurs twice so against Jill in arraylist we have the employee ids of both the Jill's

```
Map mapByLanguage = [{"Java",List<String>("1","2")},
                     {"React",List<String>("1","4")},
                     {"R",List<String>("1","4")},
                     {"Flutter",List<String>("1","4")},
                     {"C",List<String>("2")},
                     {"Cobol",List<String>("3,5")},
                     {"Node",List<String>("5")}]
```

So above we are grouping by common Languages

**Question #1**
This data is going to be huge related to merging of two organisatons , so looping through the collections
I think will not scale

**Question #2**
I have tried below code - below method groups data based on employee name but do I have to  write separate methods to group by id , by languages and then other attributes such as byAddress , byCity etc

can all of this be done in a single method which converts the list into separate Maps  ?

```
Map<String, List<String>> groupByName(List<Employee> empList) {

    Map<String, List<String>> mappedInfo = 
            empList.stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    Employee::getName,
                    emp -> {
                        List list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add(emp.getEmpId());
                        return list;
                    },
                    (s, a) -> {
                        s.add(a.get(0));
                        return s;
                    }
                )
            );
    return mappedInfo;
}
```

**Question #3**
I have yet to transpose the List of Languages contained within each employee into above solution
am stumped on how to go about it .....
I dont want to loop through each employee for each of their languages

Comment: Regarding `Map m1 >> key = id , value = List<String> containing id which are same `, isn't the original map distinct, meaning only one `Employee` object for each ID? So it makes no sense to map a list of `Employee` objects to ID when that list will have only a single element.

Comment: agree and I have already stated the same regarding ID , but for sake of brevity I did not mention the various other attributes / fields of employee for which I need to group

Comment: corrected employee instance variable names

Comment: Why not use the full employee object in the map lists? The amount of memory consumed is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brevity, let’s use a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) in Java 16+ to hold our sample employee data. A record is appropriate when the main purpose of communicating data transparently and immutably. The compiler implicitly creates the default constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
public record Employee( int id , String name , List < String > languages ) { }
```

We could just as well use a conventional class for earlier than Java 16.

```java
package work.basil.emp;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class Employee {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final List < String > languages;

    public Employee ( int id , String name , List < String > languages ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.languages = languages;
    }

    public int id () { return id; }

    public String name () { return name; }

    public List < String > languages () { return languages; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj ) {
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass() ) return false;
        var that = ( Employee ) obj;
        return this.id == that.id &&
                Objects.equals( this.name , that.name ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.languages , that.languages );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode () {
        return Objects.hash( id , name , languages );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Employee[" +
                "id=" + id + ", " +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "languages=" + languages + ']';
    }
}
```

Make some example data.

```java
List < Employee > employees =
        List.of(
                new Employee( 1 , "Jack" , List.of( "Java" , "React" , "R" , "Flutter" ) ) ,
                new Employee( 2 , "Jill" , List.of( "Java" , "C" ) ) ,
                new Employee( 3 , "Mark" , List.of( "Cobol" ) ) ,
                new Employee( 4 , "Michael" , List.of( "React" , "R" , "Flutter" ) ) ,
                new Employee( 5 , "Jill" , List.of( "Node" , "Cobol" ) )
        );
```

## Name in common

Make your new map to organize by property. Here we are mapping each name to a set of employees sharing that name.

```
Map < String, Set < Integer > > nameInCommonMap = new HashMap <>();
```

For each of our employee objects, assign it a set. This is known as a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), when a key maps to a collection of values rather than a single value. The [`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) method makes it easy to make a multipmap by creating our nested collection for every new entry before we put the new key.

```java
for ( Employee employee : employees ) {
    nameInCommonMap.computeIfAbsent( employee.name() , k -> new HashSet < Integer >() ).add( employee.id() );
}
```

Lastly, I believe it is generally best to return unmodifiable collections whenever practical. So let's make our multipmap unmodifiable in two steps. First step: Replace each nested set of employee objects with an [unmodifiable set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable) by calling [`Set.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) in Java 10+.

```
nameInCommonMap.replaceAll( ( k , v ) -> Set.copyOf( v ) ); // Make nested set unmodifiable.
```

Second step: Make an [unmodifiable map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) by calling [`Map.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)).

```
nameInCommonMap = Map.copyOf( nameInCommonMap ); // Make outer map unmodifiable.
```

And we are done.

```
nameInCommonMap = {Mark=[3], Michael=[4], Jill=[5, 2], Jack=[1]}
```

## Language in common

The logic is nearly the same to get your map of language to set of employee IDs for employees having that language contained in their nested list. The only catch is that within our loop of `Employee` objects, we must add a nested loop of languages.

Entire example class:

```java
package work.basil.emp;

import java.util.*;

public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo () {
        record Employee( int id , String name , List < String > languages ) { }
        
        List < Employee > employees =
                List.of(
                        new Employee( 1 , "Jack" , List.of( "Java" , "React" , "R" , "Flutter" ) ) ,
                        new Employee( 2 , "Jill" , List.of( "Java" , "C" ) ) ,
                        new Employee( 3 , "Mark" , List.of( "Cobol" ) ) ,
                        new Employee( 4 , "Michael" , List.of( "React" , "R" , "Flutter" ) ) ,
                        new Employee( 5 , "Jill" , List.of( "Node" , "Cobol" ) )
                );

        Map < String, Set < Integer > > languageInCommonMap = new HashMap <>();
        for ( Employee employee : employees ) {
            for ( String language : employee.languages() ) {
                languageInCommonMap.computeIfAbsent( language , k -> new HashSet < Integer >() ).add( employee.id() );
            }
        }
        languageInCommonMap.replaceAll( ( k , v ) -> Set.copyOf( v ) ); // Make nested set unmodifiable.
        languageInCommonMap = Map.copyOf( languageInCommonMap ); // Make outer map unmodifiable.

        System.out.println( "languageInCommonMap = " + languageInCommonMap );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
languageInCommonMap = {React=[4, 1], Cobol=[5, 3], Java=[2, 1], Flutter=[4, 1], Node=[5], C=[2], R=[4, 1]}
```

## Your Questions

### Question #1 This data is going to be huge related to merging of two organisatons , so looping through the collections I think will not scale

This seems to be a contradiction. Your Question and examples start with collections. That means all the data of those collections is already in memory. Looping the data in memory to create new data structures containing that same data will not take much more memory.

All the object references being copied between the old and new collections are just that, object references. The objects (employee name string, language string, etc.) are not being copied.

### Question #2 … can all of this be done in a single method which converts the list into separate Maps ?

Perhaps.

But I do not see much benefit. The code I showed here is only four lines: establishing a map in one line, and 3 lines of a `for` loop to populate that map.

The amount of work being done is the same, whether you use streams or loops.

### Question #3 I have yet to transpose the List of Languages contained within each employee … I don’t want to loop through each employee for each of their languages

There is no getting around the looping.

Either you loop the nested language list, or you call a utility such as a stream to loop the nested language list.

There is no magical "extract out the data" operation in computing that avoids touching each data element under examination.

Comment: first - thank you for the detailed explanation . One doubt: to get the List of Languages I see you have two loops one for each employee and one for iterating each language for the employee . I am no expert , but just wondering will this be an expensive operation ?

Comment: @akila Why would you think that is expensive? By what other mechanism could you possibly do the work? How can you process each language for each employee without looking at each language for each employee? See my last section, addressing your Question # 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employees = List.of(
        new Employee("1", "Jack", List.of("Java", "React", "R", "Flutter")),
        new Employee("2", "Jill", List.of("Java", "C")),
        new Employee("3", "Mark", List.of("Cobol")),
        new Employee("4", "Michael", List.of("React", "R", "Flutter")),
        new Employee("5", "Jill", List.of("Node", "Cobol")));

    Map<String, List<String>> mapById = employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpId, e -> List.of(e.getEmpId())));
    Map<String, List<String>> mapByName = employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName,
            Collectors.mapping(Employee::getEmpId, Collectors.toList())));
    Map<String, List<String>> mapByLanguage = employees.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getLanguages().stream()
            .map(l -> Map.entry(l, e.getEmpId())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(mapById);
    System.out.println(mapByName);
    System.out.println(mapByLanguage);
}
```

output:

```
{1=[1], 2=[2], 3=[3], 4=[4], 5=[5]}
{Michael=[4], Mark=[3], Jill=[2, 5], Jack=[1]}
{Java=[1, 2], R=[1, 4], C=[2], Node=[5], Cobol=[3, 5], Flutter=[1, 4], React=[1, 4]}
```

For java8

```
    Map<String, List<String>> mapByLanguage = employees.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getLanguages().stream()
            .map(l -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(l, e.getEmpId())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Or

```
    Map<String, List<String>> mapByLanguage = employees.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getLanguages().stream()
            .map(l -> new String[] {l, e.getEmpId()}))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e[0],
            Collectors.mapping(e -> e[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your example for 'mapByLanguage ' and the code refuses to compile ( Java 8 ) - 
/**Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Map<String,List<String>>
 - Type safety: The method collect(Collector) belongs to the raw type Stream. References to generic type Stream<T> should be 
  parameterized
The type Map.Entry does not define getKey(Object) that is applicable here**/

Comment: @akila Added for Java8

Comment: thanks but unfortunately still throwing compilation errors

Comment: @akila Added another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *reflection* to iterate over declared fields dynamically and use the best feature of Java 8, stream, to achieve your goal.

Do this:

```
Field[] fields = Employee.class.getDeclaredFields();

Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (field.getType() == List.class) {
        result.put(field.getName(), employees.stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getLanguages().stream()
                        .map(l -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(l, e.getEmpId())))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                Collectors.toList()))));
    } else {
        result.put(field.getName(), employees.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> (String) callGetter(e, field.getName()),
                        Collectors.mapping(Employee::getEmpId,
                                Collectors.toList()))));
    }
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Here, the callGetter method is like below:

```
private static Object callGetter(Object obj, String fieldName) {
    PropertyDescriptor pd;
    try {
        pd = new PropertyDescriptor(fieldName, obj.getClass());
        return pd.getReadMethod().invoke(obj);
    } catch (IntrospectionException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

And the program gives you the result as following map:

```
{empId={1=[1], 2=[2], 3=[3], 4=[4], 5=[5]}, 
languages={Java=[1, 2], R=[1, 4], C=[2], Node=[5], Cobol=[3, 5], Flutter=[1, 4], React=[1, 4]}, 
name={Michael=[4], Mark=[3], Jill=[2, 5], Jack=[1]}}
```